# Did the Engineers breed the Yautja?

Tags: alien-vs.-predator

In the AVP franchise of graphic novels, books, computer games and films, the Engineers, Yautja (Predators) and Xenomorphs are shown to inhabit the same universe and have inhabited (maybe not at the same time) some of the same planets i.e. LV-1201. With the Yautja invariably breeding and hunting the Xenomorphs.

The Engineers in this universe also seem to have seeded life on many planets, and are responsible for the creation of the Xenomorph.

**Is it ever mentioned that the Engineers are also responsible for the creation of the Yautja?**

Answer (score 1):

There is only one theory that the predators were descendants of primitive mammalian precursors called Therapsids that had somehow been taken away from earth by a greater intelligence to fulfill their evolutionary potential.
And that is a theory made by a comic book character  Dr. Bergstrom.
So the origins of our favourite shrimp face hunters is still unknown.